# ImportError : import dj_database_url ImportError: No module named 'dj_database_url'

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, heroku

I am attempting to use Django + Heroku + all necessary dependencies to create my app.

After following these steps :

[migrating an existing django project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#migrating-an-existing-django-project)

However I keep getting this error when I ran `python3 manage.py runserver`:

> import dj_database_url
>   ImportError: No module named 'dj_database_url'

I have tried to fix it with [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683367/heroku-django-no-module-named-dj-database-url)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444819/django-dont-see-dj-database-url)

THIS is my code :

I imported the dj-database-url

```
import dj_database_url

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

I added the follow STATIC assets necessitities

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

THIS is in my requirements.txt file

> dj-database-url==0.4.2
>
> gunicorn==19.7.1
>
> whitenoise==3.3.0

I am still getting the `ImportError`. How do I fix this?

Comment: is this error on the local server or just on Heroku ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja I am not sure. The error path is this : 

`/Users/iivri.andre/virtualenvironment/new_app/Tut/Tut/settings.py, line 14,`

I think it is local

Comment: output of `pip freeze` contains `dj-database-url`? installed it in virtual environment? restarted gunicorn? tried with django development server?

Comment: @SachinKukreja After I followed these steps :

 [migrate existing django project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#migrating-an-existing-django-project) 

I ran `python3 manage.py runserver` so I am not sure I did anything to `gunicorn`

Comment: Don't forget to commit changes before pushing or you will keep getting the same error

Answer (score 3):

The database url is to hook/connect your db with Heroku. Try this approach.

```
if 'DATABASE_URL' in os.environ:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))
    }
else:
    print("Postgres URL not found, using sqlite instead")
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

Also, check if you added the `DATABASE_URL` into the `config vars` in Heroku settings. In addition, also check if in the `config vars` you added your `SECRET_KEY` and if you configured proper your ``` ALLOWED_HOSTS`` as they have to be states like this in your ```settings.py``` :

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['<your-app-name>.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']
```

And your `requirement.txt` have to look like this:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.24
django-forms-bootstrap==3.1.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pytz==2019.3
whitenoise==5.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the library using something like

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip install dj-database-url==0.4.2
```

or

```
.env/bin/pip install dj-database-url==0.4.2
```

?

Comment: I used `pip install dj-database-url` from [migrating an existing django project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#migrating-an-existing-django-project)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView, PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetCompleteView

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        'accounts/password_reset/',
        PasswordResetView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset'
    ),
    url(
        'accounts/password_reset_done/',
        PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_done'
    ),
    url(
        'accounts/password_reset_confirm/',
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    url(
        'accounts/password_reset_complete/',
        PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
        name='password_reset_complete'
    ),
]
```